# How to send message to multiple clients in a list from server

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, bind, serversocket

I had tried the following code as server to send message to the clients whose ip is in List mSession

```
for (MSession mSession : mSessions)
{
   System.out.println("Inside for each");
   System.out.println("IP TEST : " + mSession.getRemote_Addr());
   ServerSocket srvr = new ServerSocket(1324, 5, InetAddress.getByName(mSession.getRemote_Addr()));
   Socket skt = srvr.accept();
   System.out.println("IP1:" + InetAddress.getByName(mSession.getRemote_Host()));
   System.out.println("IP2:" + skt.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());           
   System.out.print("Server has connected!\n");
   PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);
   System.out.print("Sending string: '" + data + "'\n");
   out.print(data);
   out.close();
   skt.close();
   srvr.close();                                         
}
```

The client side code:

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName(host[0]);
System.out.println("IP SERVER : " + ip);
Socket skt = new Socket(ip, 1324);// Ip address of server
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));
System.out.print("Received string: ");

while (!in.ready()) {}
data = in.readLine();
System.out.println(in.readLine());

System.out.print("'\n");
Popupapp app = new Popupapp();
app.fdis(data);
in.close();
skt.close();
```

I am getting bindexception cannot assign requested address : JVM_Bind
I have tried other ports but the exception remains the same
I had tried ports 8080, 8089,8086,8009,1234,8242,8006

Please help me to fix this.

I had tried on this simple program and it is showing same exception

```
public class ServerSide extends Thread{

public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        String data = "Recieved new notification";
        try {

             ServerSocket srvr = new ServerSocket(1234, 5, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.168.40"));
             Socket skt = srvr.accept();

             skt.getInputStream();

             System.out.print("Server has connected!\n");
             PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);
             System.out.print("Sending string: '" + data + "'\n");
             out.print(data);
             out.close();
             skt.close();
             srvr.close();
             Thread.sleep(500);



      }

   catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.print("Whoops! It didn't work!\n" + e);
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
   }

}
}
```

Comment: Are you running both server and client from one JVM (i.e. one main for buth)

Comment: no both are in different systems

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you're creating server socket inside the foreach loop. So, after the first time, when the first client is processed and the serversocket is created for the first time, this code again tries to create another serversocket on the same port in the next client processing, thereby resulting in the bind-exception.

The solution is to create a separate serversocket before the loop, which would keep on accepting clients inside the foreach loop. It is shown below :

```
ServerSocket srvr = new ServerSocket(1324, 5, InetAddress.getByName(mSession.getRemote_Addr()));
for (MSession mSession : mSessions)
              {
                  System.out.println("Inside for each");
                  System.out.println("IP TEST : " + mSession.getRemote_Addr());
                  // start accepting client-requests                     
                  Socket skt = srvr.accept();
                  System.out.println("IP1:" + InetAddress.getByName(mSession.getRemote_Host()));
                  System.out.println("IP2:" + skt.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());            
                  System.out.print("Server has connected!\n");
                  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);
                  System.out.print("Sending string: '" + data + "'\n");
                  out.print(data);
                  out.close();
                  skt.close();                                     
              }
                // finally close the server-socket!                
                  srvr.close();
```

---

Based on your **EDIT :**

You're again creating your ServerSocket inside the loop! **DON'T!!!*** Do it in the constructor(or in some another method).

```
public class ServerSide extends Thread{

public ServerSide(){
ServerSocket srvr = new ServerSocket(1234, 5, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.168.40"));
}
public void run()
{
while(true)
{
    String data = "Recieved new notification";
    try {             
         Socket skt = srvr.accept();
         skt.getInputStream();
         System.out.print("Server has connected!\n");
         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);
         System.out.print("Sending string: '" + data + "'\n");
         out.print(data);
         out.close();
         skt.close();
         srvr.close();
         Thread.sleep(500);
  }
catch(Exception e) {
  System.out.print("Whoops! It didn't work!\n" + e);
  try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Now, call it from your main-method on the server-side like :

```
new ServerSide().start();
```

Comment: How can i go through all the clients in the list

Comment: Now this is accessing only one client

Comment: @AntonyJoslin - You're already going through the client sockets in the list. I assume mSessions is some sort of collection/list. So, you're processing clients in order of how you added them in the list. Are you sure that multiple clients are running && you've added them into your collection/list, before accepting them?

Comment: I am using this for each loop to accessing all the clients in the list mSession.

Comment: Yes the clients are listening

Comment: @AntonyJoslin - If this helped, please feel free to accept the answer ---> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @am-i-helpful - I had tried the following code without any for loop this is also giving the same error

Comment: @am-i-helpful - Please look on the last code of the question

Comment: @AntonyJoslin - Firstly, you changed your question! This should not have been done here; you should've asked a separate question. But, anyways you're again making the same mistake here. I am answering this, but, please don't modify it further.

Comment: OK I just wanted you to know that i had tried that too.

Comment: I think both are caused by same mistake

Comment: @AntonyJoslin - I've answered it, I hope it will work for you. Please accept the answer if it answered your queries!

Comment: Thank you for the answer I will try what you had suggested

Comment: @AntonyJoslin - Now, please accept the answer. See how to accept the answer ---> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.